# EEG data using Arduino Mega 2560 and RS232 vs Bluetooth

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, serial-port, eeglab

I have to send EEG data from Arduino using RS232 or Bluetooth to PC and save it to a file. I use my own active eelctrodes. I'm totally new in Arduino world and it's hart to find something which makes sense. Could you give me some advices where I should start. How can I receive EEG data? What is better/easier -using RS232 or Bluetooth? How read data in Matlab in real time?
Any helpful links or websites will be appreciated. I use openeeg website to built the device.

Greetings Alex

Answer (score 0):

Which one is better? That depends on your application, is a wired connection important? if not bluetooth is probably the better option. You will probably find more documentation and support for the Bluetooth as well. The HC-05 module is a good starting place for arduino.

Matlab provides a tutorial on how to read data from a remote BT device: https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ug/instructions-on-pairing-bluetooth-device.html